# Redshift: Executing a dynamic query from a string

Tags: sql, dynamic, amazon-redshift

I would like to execute a dynamic SQL query stored in a string field on Amazon Redshift.

My background is mostly T-SQL relational databases. I used to build SQL statements dynamically, store them into variables and them execute them. I know Redshift can prepare and execute statements, but I wonder if it is possible to execute a query stored in a string field.

I have a piece of code that dynamically builds the code below with stats on several tables using pg_* system tables. Every column/table name is dynamically calculated. Here's an example of the query output:

```sql
SELECT h_article_id AS key, 'transport_parameters_weight_in_grams' AS col_name, COUNT(DISTINCT transport_parameters_weight_in_grams) AS count_value FROM dv.s_products GROUP BY h_article_id UNION ALL
SELECT h_article_id AS key, 'transport_parameters_width_in_mm' AS col_name, COUNT(DISTINCT transport_parameters_width_in_mm) AS count_value FROM dv.s_products GROUP BY h_article_id UNION ALL
SELECT h_article_id AS key, 'label_owner_info_communication_address' AS col_name, COUNT(DISTINCT label_owner_info_communication_address) AS count_value FROM dv.s_products GROUP BY h_article_id
```

I would like to input this dynamic piece of code within another query, so I can make some statistics, like so:

```sql
SELECT col_name, AVG(count_value*1.00) AS avg_count
FROM (
  'QUERY ABOVE'
) A
GROUP BY col_name;
```

This would ouput something like:

```
col_name                                avg_count
transport_parameters_weight_in_grams    1.00
transport_parameters_width_in_mm        1.00
label_owner_info_communication_address  0.60
```

The natural way for me to do this would be to store everything as a string in a variable and execute it. But I'm afraid Redshift does not support this.

Is there an alternative way to really build dynamic SQL code?

Answer (score 8):

This is possible now that we have added support for Stored Procedures. ["Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

For example, this stored procedure counts the rows in a table and inserts the table name and row count into another table. Both table names are provided as input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_tbl_count(IN source_tbl VARCHAR, IN count_tbl VARCHAR) AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(count_tbl) 
        || ' SELECT ''' || source_tbl ||''', COUNT(*) FROM ' 
        || quote_ident(source_tbl) || ';' 
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In your example the query to executed could be passed in as a string.

Comment: How about if you needed to add an IF statement? For example if you needed to add a WHERE or an AND to the SELECT statement based on the vale of one of the parameters. Would you declare a string, set that up and then EXECUTE it?

Comment: Several example stored procedure are provided on GitHub. They have examples of using conditional dynamic SQL creation. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/StoredProcedures

Answer (score 3):

No. There is not a straightforward way to run dynamic built SQL code in Redshift.

You can't define SQL variables, or create stored procedures, as you would have in MS SQL Server.

You can create [Python Functions in Redshift](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1IHV1G67CY53T/Introduction-to-Python-UDFs-in-Amazon-Redshift), but you would be coding in Python vs. SQL.

You can use the ["PREPARE" and "EXECUTE" statements to run "pre-defined" SQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html) queries, but you would have to create the statements outside of the database, before passing them to the execute command. By creating the statement outside of the database, in a way defeats the purpose.... You can create any statement in your "favorite" programming language.

As I said, this SQL based, in-database dynamic SQL does not exist.

Basically, you need to run this logic in your application or using something such as AWS Data Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
You say "you would have to create the statements outside of the database, before passing them to the execute". I know I can pass statements, but they are almost hard coded (aside from the $ variable). Imagine I have a table with a column containing several SQL queries. Would it be possible to pass those queries to the `EXECUTE` command?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but youhave to "PREPARE" them first.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know how would that be possible. Consider a table A with a varchar column "query" containing select queries.

This is the example of a `prepare` statement, but it seems too hardcoded.  `PREPARE prep_select_plan (int) 
AS select * from prep1 where c1 = $1;`

How would I reference a query that is contained in a varchar field of another table?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Postgre on Redshift, and I ran into this issue and found a solution.

I was trying to create a dynamic query, putting in my own date.

```
date = dt.date(2018, 10, 30)

query = ''' select * from table where date >= ''' + str(my_date) + ''' order by date '''
```

But, the query entirely ignores the condition when typing it this way.

However, if you use the percent sign (%), you can insert the date correctly.

The correct way to write the above statement is:

```
query = ''' select * from table where date >= ''' + ''' '%s' ''' % my_date + ''' order by date '''
```

So, maybe this is helpful, or maybe it is not. I hope it helps at least one person in my situation!

Best wishes.