# Pivot Table with Redshift (PostgreSQL) with Count

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

I'm facing a challenge with Redshift:
I'm trying to dynamically move rows into columns and aggregate by count, however I noticed the pivot table feature is only available from PostgreSQL 9.

Any idea about how to do the following?

```
 index   fruit     color 
 1       apple     red           
 2       apple     yellow           
 2       banana    blue           
 2       banana    blue           
 3       banana    blue     
 3       banana    green     
 3       pear      green     
 3       pear      red
```

to:

```
 index   red       yellow    blue    green 
 1       1         0         0       0
 2       0         1         2       0
 3       1         0         1       2
```

Essentially, grouping and counting occurrences of color per id (fruit is not so important, although I'll use it as a filter later).

Note: I might also want to do a binary transformation later on (i.e 0 for 0 and 1 if > 0)

Edit: If the above is not possible, any way to do this instead ?

```
 index   color     count     
 1       red       1        
 1       yellow    0           
 1       blue      0
 1       green     0 
 2       red       0        
 2       yellow    1           
 2       blue      2
 2       green     0
 3       red       1         
 3       yellow    0           
 3       blue      1
 3       green     2
```

(again blue,yellow,blue and green should be dynamic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Edit, you could do

```
select x.index, x.color, sum(case when y.index is not null then 1 else 0 end) as count
from 
((select index
from [table]
group by index
order by index) a
inner join 
(select color
from [table]
group by color
order by color) b
on 1 = 1) x
left outer join
[table] y
on x.index = y.index
and x.color = y.color
group by x.index, x.color
order by x.index, x.color
```

Answer (score 0):

If `PIVOT` is not available in Redshift, then you could always just use a standard pivot query:

```
SELECT
    index,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS red,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yellow,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'blue'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'green'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS green
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY index
```

Comment: Thanks ! But that means I have to know 'red', 'yellow', 'blue' etc. in advance? What if I don't ?

Comment: Then you would need to use dynamic SQL for that, [which appears to be not supported for Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332772/redshift-executing-a-dynamic-query-from-a-string).

Comment: which is not available in Redshift ?