# Issue with passing column name as a parameter to "PREPARE" in Redshift

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, amazon-redshift

I am using REDSHIFT for the below question, Here is problem and I am looking for solution.

I have 2 tables, one table contains the column combinations on which the second table should group the results by.

Table 1 containing column combinations (This is output from a stored procedure):

```
COMBINATIONS

fruit_combinations 
  banana,'ALL'  
  banana, orange
```

Table 2 containing fruit_baskets:

```
FRUIT_BASKET

BANANA ORANGE USER_COUNT 
  b1     o1      5
  b1     o2      10
```

Result set:

```
FRUIT_BASKET_AGG

BANANA   ORANGE    USER_COUNT 
  b1     'ALL'       15
  b1      o1         5
  b1      o2         10
```

Tried solution in Redshift:

```
PREPARE executesql(VARCHAR(10),VARCHAR(10))
AS 
select $1,$2, sum(fb.user_Count) as user_count
from dv_product.fruit_basket fb
group by 1,2;

EXECUTE executesql("BANANA","ORANGE") ;
DEALLOCATE executesql;

Error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "banana" does not exist;
```

Questions:

1 - Is there a way I can pass column names as parameter to a sql statement and execute the sql?

2 - What is other alternative to achieve the result set mentioned above in Redshift?

Comment: As a parameter? Simply No, you can't pass identifiers as a parameters, you need a dynamic SQL to do so.

Comment: Thank you Sami. Redshift does not support dynamic sql. Is there any other way to get the result set apart from "PREPARE"?

Comment: No, sorry I dunno about Redshift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift: Executing a dynamic query from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332772/redshift-executing-a-dynamic-query-from-a-string)

Comment: There is a slight change that the new [Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) functionality might be able to assist, but I suspect it would have the same limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can *now* be done using Stored Procedures without the need for `PREPARE`. ["Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

It seems like you are trying to emulate `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP` functionality. I have added a `UNION ALL` to the dynamic SQL to provide this type of output.

For this example stored procedure, both column names are provided as input and a `REFCURSOR` is declared as output.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_fruit_sum(IN column_1 VARCHAR, IN column_2 VARCHAR, result_set INOUT REFCURSOR) AS $$
BEGIN
OPEN result_set FOR
EXECUTE 'SELECT '|| quote_ident(column_1) ||' , '|| quote_ident(column_2) 
        || ' , SUM(fb.user_Count) as user_count ' 
        || 'FROM dv_product.fruit_basket fb GROUP BY 1,2'
        || 'UNION ALL '
        || 'SELECT '|| quote_ident(column_1) ||' , ''ALL'''
        || ' , SUM(fb.user_Count) as user_count ' 
        || 'FROM dv_product.fruit_basket fb GROUP BY 1;'  
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You specify the columns and the output REFCURSOR when calling the procedure. The column names could be retrieved from a table by another stored procedure if needed. Then fetch the output from the REFCURSOR.

```
BEGIN; 
CALL get_fruit_sum ( 'Banana','Orange','result_set' ); 
FETCH ALL FROM result_set; 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is very helpful. How does the cursor perform on a huge result set?

Comment: For hundreds of rows to 10s of thousands of rows `REFCURSOR` is fine. For millions of rows I would recommend sending results to a temp table instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html