# Can redshift stored procs be used to make a date range UNION ALL query

Tags: amazon-redshift

Since redshift does not natively support date partitioning, other than in redshift spectrum, all our tables are date partitioned

```
my_table_name_YYYY_MM_DD
```

So every time we do queries it's usually looks like this

```
select columns, i, want from
(select * from tbl1_date UNION ALL 
select * from tbl2_date UNION ALL 
select * from tbl3_date UNION ALL 
select * from tbl4_date);
```

Where there's one UNION ALL per day.

Can stored procedures generate a date rangeso our business analysts stop losing their hair when I send them a python or bash script to generate the date range?

Comment: Nice idea but no. Can't do that. Did you try using date as a sort key? Redshift doesn't do partitioning (except when using spectrum) - I suggest you don't try to force it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could create a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL using only the needed tables. See my answer here for a template to start from: [Issue with passing column name as a parameter to "PREPARE" in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029636/issue-with-passing-column-name-as-a-parameter-to-prepare-in-redshift/56045349#56045349)

However, you should be aware that Redshift is able to achieve most of what you want automatically using a "Time Series Table" view. This documented here:

- [Using Time Series Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-time-series-tables.html)
- [Use Time-Series Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-time-series-tables.html)

You define a view that is composed of a UNION ALL over a sequence of identical tables with a sort key defined on a commonly filtered date or timestamp column. When you query that view Redshift is able to eliminate the scans on any UNION'ed tables that would not contain relevant data.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  store_sales_vw
AS        SELECT * FROM store_sales_1998
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM store_sales_1999
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM store_sales_2001
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM store_sales_2002
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM store_sales_2003
; 

SELECT cd.cd_education_status
      ,COUNT(*) sales_count
      ,AVG(ss_quantity) avg_quantity
FROM store_sales_vw vw
JOIN customer_demographics cd
ON vw.ss_cdemo_sk = cd.cd_demo_sk
WHERE ss_sold_ts BETWEEN '1999-09-01' AND '2000-08-31'
GROUP BY cd.cd_education_status
```

In this example Redshift will only use the `store_sales_1999` and `store_sales_2000` tables, skipping the other tables in the view. Note that the table skipping is not based the name of the table. Redshift knows the MIN and MAX values of the sort key timestamp in each table.

If you purse this approach please be sure to keep the total size of the UNION fairly low. I recommend (at most) daily tables for the last week [7], weekly tables for the last month [5], quarterly tables for the last year [4], and then yearly tables for older data.

You can use [ALTER TABLE … APPEND](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html) to merge the daily tables in weekly tables and so on.