# How to run a SQL query stored inside Redshift table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to run a SQL query which is stored as varchar in Redshift table. Is there a way to achieve the same? Here's what I want:

```
--if we have a text script like this
insert into schema_1.table_1 (id, script) values (1, 'select count(*) from 
schema_2.table_2;');
--is there any way to run this script in SQL?
RunString(select script from schema_1.table_1 where id = 1);
```

The table looks something like this:

```
___________________________________________
|Id|Query                                 |
|--|--------------------------------------|
|1 |select count(*) from schema_2.table_2;|
-------------------------------------------
```

In short, I want to run the query present in the table above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift: Executing a dynamic query from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332772/redshift-executing-a-dynamic-query-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this by [Creating Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-overview.html).

I notice that that [Supported PL/pgSQL Statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-select-into) include:

> **Dynamic SQL**
>
> To generate dynamic commands that can involve different tables or different data types each time they are run from a PL/pgSQL stored procedure, use the `EXECUTE` statement.

```
EXECUTE command-string [ INTO target ];
```

Comment: Agreed. But how is that going to help me extract the query that is already present in the table as data?

Comment: When you [CALL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CALL_procedure.html) the stored procedure, you can pass in the string containing the query. The stored procedure should then be able to pass back the result of the query.