# Redshift UDF function with dynamic SQLstatement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am very much new to Amazon redshift. I am trying to create the UDF function to create column aggregation by adding multiple columns, here is what I am tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pp_calc(identifier varchar(100),table_name varchar(100))
RETURNS float 
stable 
as $$

BEGIN

IF identifier ='OC' THEN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT identifier'||_1 + || 'identifier' ||_2 || 'FROM ' || table_name /* I want to return this addition result */
ELSE 
  'SELECT identifier'||_1 + || 'identifier' ||_2 || 'FROM ' || table_name
END IF;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Errors I am getting near return statement. I am sure there is something wrong with syntax. I want to pass the indentifer as parameter based on parameter I want to add columns.

Comment: I don't know about Redshift, but in Postgres you can only use dynamic sql in PL/pgSQL, not in `language sql` functions

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, I am getting error [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: language plpgsql not supported for CREATE FUNCTION;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a stored procedure to perform dynamic SQL. See ["Overview of Stored Procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE pp_calc(identifier varchar(100),table_name varchar(100))
RETURNS float  
AS $$
BEGIN
IF identifier ='OC' THEN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT '||identifier||'_1 + '||identifier||'_2 FROM '||table_name ;
/* I want to return this addition result */
ELSE
  EXECUTE 'SELECT '||identifier||'_1 + '||identifier||'_2 FROM '||table_name ;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See also this previous answer: [Redshift: Executing a dynamic query from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332772/redshift-executing-a-dynamic-query-from-a-string)